# Firebase Firestore composite index limit of 200 - is it reached if used in nested structure with lots of users?

Tags: firebase, indexing, limit, google-cloud-firestore, composite

I am confused about what Firestore counts toward its composite index limit of 200.

For example, let's say I have thousands of users, and each user has thousands of characters.  I want each user to be able to sort through his characters, based on different parameters about those characters.   I have the following structure, where {} indicates a wildcard:

```
users:
   {user_ID}
      user_name: {user_name}
      user_email: {user_email}
      characters:
         {characterUID}
            name:  {name}
            strength:  {strength}
            speed:  {speed}
            stamina: {stamina}
            date_created:  {timestamp}
```

So, in android, I would then do this:

```
Query query = fsDB.collection("users").document("user_ID").collection("characters")
.orderBy("strength").orderBy("name");
```

Or this:

```
Query query = fsDB.collection("users").document("user_ID").collection("characters")
.orderBy("speed").orderBy("date_created");
```

Then, I would create the composite index in Firebase Console as:

```
Collection Group:   characters

Fields Indexed:  strength , name
```

and

```
Collection Group:  characters

Fields Indexed:  speed, date_created.
```

So, is this just 2 composite indexes according to Firebase?  Or is this multiplied by the number of Users I have?

If it is multiplied by the number of users, how should I restructure my data so that I do not run into this problem?

Thanks -

Jeff

Comment: Also posted on the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZHBXNypg_D0) group.

Comment: Our project needed way more than 200. I don't think putting a hard limit on it will work on any scalable project. you will eventually need more as your projects gets larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing with Sam Stern at Firebase,

The answer is that the indexes are not multiplied by the number of users.

From Sam ----

> Indexes actually on depend on the collection name so all of the "characters" subcollections of your "users" documents can share the same indexes.
>
> You'd only approach the 200 index limit if you had 200+ different field combinations you wanted to index.  Hope that makes sense!
>
> - Sam